# Performance - String.charAt(0) vs. /^.{1}/

Tags: javascript, regex, string, performance

Which should be faster conceptually speaking?

`String.charAt(0)` or `/^.{1}/` (regex)

Comment: `'somestring'[0]` - shorter

Comment: The correct answer to "which is faster" is always "test and find out".  But offhand, "grab the first value of a string" vs "fire up the regexp engine to match the first character" sounds like the first choice should be much faster.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/charat-vs-regex-vs-prop

Comment: Joban's answer is fine other than not citing anything (you can use my perf if you're reading this).

Comment: Just for the sake, [don't choose `String.substr` either](http://jsperf.com/charat-vs-regex-vs-prop/2)

Comment: @livingston_mechanical the difference between those two might be more something to do with caching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String.charAt(0)`, regex have to be processed and applied.

**Speed Test Resource:**

> [`Paul S.`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1615483/paul-s) for the comparison test, http://jsperf.com/charat-vs-regex-vs-prop
>
> [`joseph-the-dreamer`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/575527/joseph-the-dreamer) for adding more to the test, http://jsperf.com/charat-vs-regex-vs-prop/3

Comment: [An updated test](http://jsperf.com/charat-vs-regex-vs-prop/3) with additional methods here as well. Regex is like a snail compared to the others.

Comment: why is charAt faster than []?